# Relative layouts children positions

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to adjust my layout with a button as exit on the right corner of the layout and an image button below the center of the layout. It should be accurately there to support the background for multiple screens. 
I used relative layout and inside it the image buttons, but I am unable to set the image button 2 on its position. If i do it, the whole layout is vertically expanded.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.rabiya.menu.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/rl01" >




<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/rl02"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
  android:background="@drawable/background3" >
    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/exit3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:contentDescription="@string/image"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:background="@drawable/exit" 
      />
    <TextView 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/tv01"
  android:background="#000"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/rl03"
  android:background="#00ffffff"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tv01"
  android:orientation="vertical"
   >



       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/click"
           android:contentDescription="@string/image"
           android:paddingTop="20dip" />
      <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/click"
     android:contentDescription="@string/image" 
     />
       <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:background="@drawable/click"
     android:contentDescription="@string/image" 
     />
       <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     android:background="@drawable/click"
     android:contentDescription="@string/image" 
     />


  </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your problem ? What is the issue with the code you posted ?

Comment: Please post the full code

Comment: Pardon me for not being clear. I need to adjust four buttons exactly below the center of the layout. But its not working with any combination of layouts or properties that i know

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand cleary wath yo want but seems a problems that I have
And i change my layout to the **FrameLayout** 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm

Mayby a gravity center for one and gravite up aling right  for the buton do the works

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom view extended from LinearLayour or RelativeLayout and place an image inside of it. If I understand correctly, you want to manipulate image inside of the button.

Once you have your own view with image inside of you can override on click to make it behave like button.